# Quick view of your daily rep

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It used to be that you could click the rep count at the top of the screen on your sub-site of choice, and it'd take you directly to the rep page in  your profile.

Since the new title bar, this no longer appears to happen.

So now to see how much rep I've earned, and on what for the day, I have to click my badge, page load, then scroll down and click the rep tab, page load and then see it.

Is there a shortcut that I'm missing to just find out how much rep I've earned in the present 24 hour period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the recent achievements at the top (where your rep notifications comes in/green box etc) in the drop down click any of the images at the top for the sites you got rep on.

EG I earned rep on MSO and SO today, and there is a summary at the top of the drop down showing total rep for each site next to the site's icon image.

Clicking either image takes you to your profile page right to the rep page.

Comment: Aha, so it does! Still two clicks instead of one, but at least it's faster :) Thanks!